# How to import sr_robot_msgs in Python

Tags: ros, python, shadow-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to run this code but doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('rospy_tutorials')

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import *
from stacks.shadow_robot.sr_robot_msgs.msg import JointControllerState

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id()+"I heard %s", data)
    
def listener():

    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber("sh_ffj3_mixed_position_velocity_controller/command", JointControllerState, callback)

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

the answer for this is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paulo/ros_workspace/sandbox/beginner_tutorials/scripts/listener.py", line 7, in 
    from stacks.shadow_robot.sr_robot_msgs.msg import JointControllerState
ImportError: No module named stacks.shadow_robot.sr_robot_msgs.msg
```

How to import sr_robot_msgs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60240/how-to-import-sr_robot_msgs-in-python/) by [phmferreira](https://answers.ros.org/users/4601/phmferreira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

To import it as for any other packages, make sure it is listed in the dependencies in your package manifest.xml.

Then the correct line is:

```
from sr_robot_msgs.msg import JointControllerState
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0